# Odd Issue with the Regular Build Option

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

For some reason when I press F10 to do a regular build of my project, it builds then launches with a breakpoint/arrow thing on the first curly bracket of my Main function.

What is causing this? It only happens every other time I build and it's quite annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F10 is the "Step Over" debug command. The fact that it's being built is a side effect of the editor tracking changes that you've made since the last time the project was run. So it's doing exactly what you've asked - Debug the project and step over the first instruction.

The default code to build the project is Ctr+Shift+B.

Comment: Man oh man. For some reason I thought F10 was build. xD
Thanks! Long day today...